# Vertx add handler to Spring data API

Tags: java, vert.x

In vertx if we want to execute jdbc operation that will not block main loop we use the following code,

```
client.getConnection(res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {

    SQLConnection connection = res.result();

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM some_table", res2 -> {
      if (res2.succeeded()) {

        ResultSet rs = res2.result();
        // Do something with results
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Failed to get connection - deal with it
  }
});
```

Here we add handler that will execute when our operation will be done.

Now I want to use `Spring Data API` but is it in the same way as above

Now I used it as follow

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    final EventBus eventBus = this.vertx.eventBus();
    eventBus.<String>consumer(Addresses.BEGIN_MATCH.asString(), handler-> {
        this.vertx.executeBlocking(()-> {
            final String body = handler.body();
            final JsonObject resJO = this.json.asJson(body);
            final int matchId = Integer.parseInt(resJO.getString("matchid"));
            this.matchService.beginMatch(matchId);//this service call method of crudrepository
            log.info("Match [{}] is started",matchId);
         }
    },
    handler->{});
}
```

Here I used execute blocking but it use thread from the worker pool is it any alternative to wrap blocking code?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using thread  worker pool ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: the need of using `executeBlocking` method goes away if:

- You run multiple instance of your verticle in separate pids (using systemd or docker or whatever that allows you to run independent java process safely with recovery mode) and listening the same eventbus channel in cluster mode (with hazelcast for example).
- You run multiple instance of your verticle as worker verticles as suggested by tsegismont in comment of this answer.

Also, it's not related to the question and it's really a personal opinion but I give it anyway: I think it's a bad idea to use Spring dependencies inside a vert.x application. Spring is relevant for Servlet based applications using at least Spring Core. I mean that's relevant to be used in an eco-system totally based on Spring. Otherwise you'll bring back a lot of unused big dependencies into your jar files.

You have for almost each Spring modules, small, lighter and independent libs with the same purposes. For example, for IoC you have `guice`, `hk2`, `weld`...

Personally if I need to use SQL based database, I'd be inspired by the Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and `RowMapper` model without using any Spring dependencies. It's pretty simple to reproduce that with a simple interface like that :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public interface RowMapper<T extends Serializable> {
    T map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

And another interface `DatabaseProcessor` with a method like that :

```
<T extends Serializable> List<T> execute(String query, List<QueryParam> params, RowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws SQLException;
```

And a class `QueryParam` with the value, the order and the name of your query parameters (to avoid SQL injection vulnerability).

Comment: I believe you should rephrase the first part of the answer. The verticle should be deployed as a worker verticle, with multiple instances. Then the need for executeBlocking goes away. As for second part, I think it's fine to use Spring if you have legacy code you don't want to throw away

Comment: @tsegismont I used to run my verticles independently based on multivalued systemd instances of services like this: `systemctl start myverticleA@1`, `systemctl start myverticleA@2` or based on multiple instances of a docker containers. Both case, using the eventbus in a cluster mode with hazelcast (it allows me to do more monitoring of the instances which are alive or not, and make the recovery more easier). I'll add your proposal but do you think that my way is bad? Your point of view on that question is very valuable to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tsegismont For the part on the use of spring inside vert.x: I'm not very objective but I think it's good to encourage to not start on vert.x (or even on microservices architecture in general) using the same old reflexes we had on servlet-based applications. Of course we have to remain pragmatic and sometimes we have to maintain legacy code (but in that case, I'd choose to use Spring boot instead for this kind of services).

Comment: @tsegismont There's nothing wrong with what you did - even though a SO comment is limited to fully understand :) But my point is that deploying multiple instances of a worker verticles to interact with blocking parts of an application is a common Vert.x pattern

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my answer to add this pattern